# How to specify the path for Frama-C include files?

Tags: frama-c

I have some problems to decide how to tell [Frama-C](http://frama-c.com/)
which include files to use. I usually add the option :

```
-cpp-extra-args="-I $(frama-c -print-path)/libc"
```

in order to have the standard specifications from Frama-C.
But I often need things that are not in the Frama-C library.

For example, one of the source file that I want to analyze uses a macro which is defined in `<sys/wait.h>`, 
but because Frama-C has its own `frama-c/libc/sys/wait.h`, the gcc file is not included.
Unfortunately, Frama-C doesn't define the macro, and the definition is eventually missing.
And of course, I don't want to change the source files !

I was thinking of building a local directory
with a `my_libc/sys/wait.h` file which would include
Frama-C file and in which I could copy what is missing 
from the GCC file.

I would then use :

```
-cpp-extra-args="-I my_libc -I $(frama-c -print-path)/libc"
```

But I am a bit worried by my solution since it could be quite tricky to extract definitions from GCC include files...

What do you think? Does it seem a good idea?
Do you have advice about a better organization?

Answer (score 2):

This solution seems fine (extracting definitions from gcc's headers can indeed be complicated, but you don't have much choice there: you must provide the macro at some point, and you probably don't want to have the whole header ending up in Frama-C).

I'm no pre-processing expert, but I'm not sure that you'll be able to include both `my_libc/sys/wait.h` and `$FRAMAC_SHARE/libc/sys/wait.h` with the `-cpp-extra-args` option you propose: you end up with two `sys/wait.h` headers and `cpp` will always pick the first one. I see two solutions:

- you define your own standard headers (potentially with copy'n paste from Frama-C's libc), and use only them
- you define your headers, with `#include <libc/sys/wait.h>`, and have `-cpp-extra-args=... -I$(frama-c -print-path)`, avoiding confusion on the relative path of the headers.

Note that in both cases, you must provide files for all the headers that are used by your application, even if most of them are merely a redirection to or a copy of the corresponding Frama-C file. But I guess that you should be done with a few shell commands.

Comment: thank you very much. Indeed, I cannot have both `sys/wait.h` with the `-cpp-extra-args` I gave, and your idea about using  `libc/sys/wait.h` is great. I'll try to see if I can find a way to make it clean, and let you know if I do. I was wondering how people how analyze big applications are managing this...